# option_groups_from_collection_for_select reversed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got two models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cost_centres
end
```

and

```
class CostCentre < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
end
```

I'm trying to use them to populate a grouped select box, based on what access rights a particular user has.

If a user has access at account level, they're automatically given access to all the cost centres under said account, meaning I can easily populate the select box using something like this:

```
@accounts = Account.where(id: [1,2,3])

<%= select_tag :cost_centre, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@accounts, :cost_centres, :title, :id, :name), { prompt: t(:select_a_cost_centre), class: %w(updateOptions col-md-12), :data => { :element => '#cost_centre_options' } } %>
```

Which produces something like this:

```
<select name="cost_centre" id="cost_centre" class="updateOptions col-md-12" data-element="#cost_centre_options">
    <option value="">Select A Cost Centre</option>
    <optgroup label="Conn, Gutkowski and Pouros">
        <option value="11117">Becker Inc</option>
        <option value="11119">Batz Inc</option>
        <option value="11127">Konopelski Inc</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Tillman, Collins and Kautzer">
        <option value="11136">Batz-Willms</option>
        <option value="11141">Schaefer, Reilly and Miller</option>
        <option value="11138">Paucek-Hammes</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

So far so good - the problem I have is that some users don't have account level access, and instead are only allowed access to specific cost centres.

How can I get a similar select to what I have above (that is cost centres grouped by account) after having specified the cost centres, i.e.:

```
@cost_centres = CostCentre.where(id: [1,2,3])
```

Thank you..

(PS, I did take a look here: http://gamonrails.gamov.net/post/100737980199/rails-grouped-selects - as I think this does what I need, but I wasn't able to make it work).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should work for you.

```
cost_centres = CostCentre.where(id: [1,2,3]).pluck(:account_id)
@accounts = Account.where('id in ?', cost_centres)

<%= select_tag :cost_centre, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@accounts, :cost_centres, :title, :id, :name), { prompt: t(:select_a_cost_centre), class: %w(updateOptions col-md-12), :data => { :element => '#cost_centre_options' } } %>
```

Comment: This isn't suitable as it exposes cost centres that the user doesn't have access to. i.e. 'Cost Centre A', 'Cost Centre B' and 'Cost Centre C' all belong to 'Account 1'. My user has access to A and B, but not C - but in following your suggestion, the user is going to end up with all three cost centres.